# fwrite() function in C does not write the expected answer

Tags: c, arrays, file, fwrite, fread

**Hello, everyone!**

I found a programming exercise into an old book:

"The content of the **a.txt** file is: **11 2 13 4 15 6 17 8 19** .We have the following program in C that writes something in the **b.txt** file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f, *g;
    short int v[10];

    f = fopen("a.txt", "r");
    g = fopen("b.txt", "w");

    fread(v, 8, 1, f);
    fwrite(v, 6, 1, g);

    fclose(f); fclose(g);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected my program to write these numbers: **11 2 13**
 .But instead, it wrote: **11 2 1**

I tried to see what happens with the **v** array with the Debugger, but the 
values showed there does not correspond to my calculations.

Before the fread() is called, v is uninitialized like this: **6448 64 -108 96 6542 64 6448 64 68 0**

After the fread()
function completes, the v in Debug mode is: **12593 12832 12576 8243 6542 64 6448 64 68 0**

I don't study C anymore, but I'm curious how fread() reads the numbers from a.txt and how fwrite() writes them in b.txt. I know the functions prototipes and how they generally work, because I wrote some little programs using them:

```
int fread(void *p, int dim, int n, FILE *f);
//reads n elements from f, each one having dim bytes and stores them in p

int fwrite(void *p, int dim, int n, FILE *f);
//writes n elements in f from p, each one having dim bytes
```

But in this particular case, I'm confused. I even tried to change the type of my array from **short int** to **int**, but the result is the same. I checked the book and the **int** type has 4 bytes and "short int" has 2 bytes if that helps.

Comment: Yes you read eight ***bytes*** and then you write six ***bytes***. The `fread` and `fwrite` functions doesn't deal with texts but with raw bytes.

Comment: Thank you! It reads "11 2 13 " and it writes "11 2 1" because it reads each character, including the blank space. What a dumb question I just asked =))

Comment: The contents of the `v` array, as seen in the debugger, will be much more informative if you change its type to `char`.  It's possible that your debugger has the ability to reinterpret a variable with a different type, so you might not have to recompile the program to do this.

Comment: You're right! I changed the type in **char** and I used a for loop to print each character v[i] before it's written in **b.txt**. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well fwrite works as follow (from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm)) :

> size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)

- ptr − This is the pointer to the array of elements to be written.
- size − This is the size in bytes of each element to be written.
- nmemb − This is the number of elements, each one with a size of size bytes.
- stream − This is the pointer to a FILE object that specifies an output stream.

So this line

`fwrite(v, 6, 1, g);`

Writes *6* bytes from "11 2 13 4 15 6 17 8 19". Do not forget, there are spaces in this line. So the function writes the very 6 first char (since the size, in almost every cases, of a char is 1) wich are :
`'1', '1', ' ', '2', ' ', '1'.`

Comment: Thank you! I realized that after a user called himself "Some programmer dude" told me these functions actually read/write characters. I thought for a moment they read/write integers and that's why I was not able to understand what is "wrong" with the answer!